# Google SWFObject javascript detection when video stopped or get completed play

Tags: javascript, swfobject

hiii all,

this is my very first post on stackoverflow, I always used to be a guy sitting back and see what happens here, never contributed, but now i finally got a chance..

MY question is I have a swf file, and I am playing it on my html page using SWFObject,now I want to implement a javascript method which triggers when videos gets completely played or get stopped..

### here's my code

```
<html><head>
  <title>PENSIONS BOOST</title>




<script type="text/javascript" src="https://aimhighermarketing.s3.amazonaws.com/videocontrollers/swfobject.js"></script>
</head><body>
 <div id="player" align="center">
  <script type="text/javascript">
var so = new SWFObject('https://aimhighermarketing.s3.amazonaws.com/videocontrollers/player.swf','mp1','640','480','10');
so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
so.addVariable('frontcolor','FFFFFF');
so.addVariable('lightcolor','FFFFFF');
so.addVariable('screencolor','FFFFFF');
so.addParam('flashvars','&file=HTTP://soci7361@socialnetworkbizbuilder.com/videos/pbsalesvideov2.mp4&&controlbar=none&autostart=true');

so.write('player');</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

,any kind of help is very much appreciated..
Kindly help..

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Would love to help you out, but unfortunately you are missing very important information. SWFObject is just a tool to place the object tag safely on the user's browser. Remember those days you had to click on the OBJECT tag in order to activate it? Well, SWFObject fixes that... and much more.

What we need to know is which video player are you using? Flash is actually what fires the events to a javascript, which is what you'd be listening for.

The most popular of them is usually JWPlayer or Flowplayer.

If you can let us know which one it is, or what kind of flash player you are using, I'd be happy to do some quick research for you.

---

Never mind, I just visited your SWF File and found it is JW Player 4.

Here is the JS Code to listen for event changes:

```
var player;
function playerReady(object) {
  player = document.getElementById(object.id);
    player.addModelListener("state","playerStateChanged");
}
function playerStateChanged(obj) {
    if (obj.newstate == 'COMPLETED') {
        // Your video has finished playing
    } else if (obj.oldstate == 'IDLE' AND obj.newstate == 'PLAYING') {
        // Your video started to play. Now, this is not fully accurate. IDLE can also mean they pressed STOP and sat there.
    }
}
```

In all reality, you should have a "startedVideo = false;" and on the first play change it to true. Then you'll be able to tell when it was first started playing..

Even though JWPlayer is up to version 5, they do still have a full JS API Doc online:
[JWPlayer 4 JavaScript API](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v4/12209/javascript-api-reference)